# I want to convert multiple decimal values inside an array to hexadecimal, but my code is not working as intended? How do I fix this?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, hex

My goal is to convert the decimal values stored inside the array into hexadecimal form.

While the input[0] (first loop) and sum variable(final loop) converts perfectly, the rest of the array in the middle doesn’t convert correctly. Why is that?

I’ve been fiddling around for an hour with variables and stuff but this is the closest I got to it being correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dividend,base=3,i,remainder,counter;
    
    int sum=651,input[4]={512,128,9,5},x=4;
    
    char hex[1024];


if(base==3)
    {
        printf("\nThe number system is: Hexadecimal\n"); 
        printf("The converted number is/are: ");
        
        for(i=0;i<=x;i++)
        {
            if(i==x)
                {dividend=sum;}
            else
                {dividend=input[i];}

            while(dividend!=0)
            {
                remainder=dividend%16;
                dividend/=16;
                
                if (remainder < 10)
                {hex[counter++] = 48 + remainder;}
                else
                {hex[counter++] = 55 + remainder;}
            }
            for(;counter>=0;counter--)
            {
                printf("%c",hex[counter]);
            }
            printf(",");
            counter=0;          
        }
    }   
}
```

Output

```
The number system is: Hexadecimal
The converted number is/are: 200,280,89,85,28B,
```

Expected Output

```
The number system is: Hexadecimal
The converted number is/are: 200,80,9,5,28B,
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to null-terminate your strings.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Never mind, I'm wrong.  It's a little more complicated than that.

Comment: Let's say you construct a 2-digit number like `80`.  So after the `while(dividend!=0)` loop finishes, your `counter` variable will contain `2`.  So your `for(;counter>=0;counter--)` loop will run `2`, `1`, `0`.  It will print *three* digits, not two.  And it will tend to print one of the digits of the previous answer.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, here's a tip: Code like this is much easier to read if you write `hex[counter++] = '0' + remainder;` and `hex[counter++] = 'A' + remainder - 10;`.  That way nobody has to waste time looking up codes in an ASCII chart.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. That makes so much sense, so essentially there are some stray characters accidentally included from the previous loop… also the tip is very helpful since someone in our group has to explain this and might be confused regarding the ASCII part.

Comment: I figured it out HAHAHA. I just initialized counter-- inside the for loop and it removed the additional counter . Again thanks for the help